# Kubernetes on AWS Master node problems

Tags: kubernetes

After running Kubernetes on AWS for a few days, my master node goes dead.  This has happened after setting up 2 different clusters.  The pods are still running and available, but there's no way to manage / proxy.

Question is why?  Or alternatively, how do I replace the master node on AWS?  Or alternatively, how do I debug the existing one?  Or alternatively, how do I use something other than a t2.micro, which may be too small to run master?

Symptom:
    $ kubectl get pods
    error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://**.###.###.###/api: dial tcp **.###.###.###:443: connection refused

Edit: 
This is what I found after further debugging:

```
goroutine 571 [running]:
net/http.func·018()
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:517 +0x2a
net/http.(*Transport).CancelRequest(0xc2083c0630, 0xc209750d00)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/transport.go:284 +0x97
github.com/coreos/go-etcd/etcd.func·003()
    /go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/coreos/go-etcd/etcd/requests.go:159 +0x236
created by github.com/coreos/go-etcd/etcd.(*Client).SendRequest
    /go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/coreos/go-etcd/etcd/requests.go:168 +0x3e3

goroutine 1 [IO wait, 12 minutes]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc20870e760, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc20870e760, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc20870e700, 0x0, 0x7f4424a42008, 0xc20930a168)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:419 +0x40b
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0xc20804bec0, 0x5bccce, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:234 +0x4e
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0xc20804bec0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/server.go:1976 +0x4c
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc20887ec60, 0x7f4424a66dc8, 0xc20804bec0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/server.go:1728 +0x92
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc20887ec60, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/src/go/src/net/http/server.go:1718 +0x154
github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/app.(*APIServer).Run(0xc2081f0e00, 0xc20806e0e0, 0x0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go:484 +0x264a
main.main()
        /go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/apiserver.go:48 +0x154
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of debugging?  As with any service, the first things to check is (a) is the service runing? And (b) did it log any errors in the system log or in the application log?

Comment: I should note, master is up, but I can't ssh in.  I would imagine that there is something like a file descriptor leak, but who knows?

Comment: Setting a larger master (from browsing github)
export MASTER_SIZE=XXX

Comment: This is the error that i got before it went down: I0822 19:58:56.619416       7 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.0:1111: EOF

Comment: I have the exact same issues and questions as @JuanIsFree. And I guess another related question worth asking is isn't having a single master node, a single point of failure? Is there a way to have more than one master, just in case one fails?

Comment: I found that it's possible from the documentation, but it looks like the aws tool doesn't create the cluster this way yet:  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/high-availability.md#replicated-api-servers

Comment: @Pouria Yes and no. Unlike many cluster tools, there is no effect to the underlying workloads if the master goes down. That is to say, if it goes down, you can't control them (until you bring the master up), but they keep on chugging along. So technically, you are correct, but it's not a serious issue. HA is being worked on right now, and is likely to be available on the order of months (if not sooner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly that the initial size of machine was too low, and ran out of memory (or something similar). To use a larger cluster size, follow this link[1] and set an environment variable before you bring up your cluster.

In this case, something like:

```
export MINION_SIZE=t2.large
```

Should run forever.[2]

[1] http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/

[2] Or reasonable approximation thereof. :)